# how to read the value from excel in c# without using third party dll?

Tags: c#

I have a excel file which is named **strings.xls** in **C:**

[image]

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        string workbookPath = "c:/strings.xls"; 

        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = null;

        try
        {
            excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0,
                false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true,
                false, 0, true, false, false);
        }
        catch
        {
            excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        }
        Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
        string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
        Excel.Range excelCell = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
        excelCell.Value2 = "Hi There";
```

Comment: _What have you tried so far?_ Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Why? What's the benefit of not using an existing library? And by "third party", do you include non BCL Microsoft made libraries?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [Jet OLE DB Provide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934)r With Microsoft Excel Workbooks to read values from excel. This is good codeproject article with example code for [oledb with excel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB).

You can also use do it using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5123/Opening-and-Navigating-Excel-with-C) would be good starting point.

Comment: is it possible to using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ?

Comment: but i don't know that how to achieve this. please give me a code snippet.

Comment: I use the code what you mentioned before. It is adding the value when the file does not exist in the relevant path. But i want to get the values from the strings.xls file as dictionary. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Since this is XLS file (a binary format), the simplest solution would be to use Excel (Microsoft Jet) OLE DB driver to retrieve that value. [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB)

If you can change the process to provide XLSX files then you could open then in plain .NET and parse the values out of the XML files.

Comment: Unrelated to the OP but can you really parse .xlsx files without any third party libraries (plain old .Net)?

Comment: yes, using System.IO.Packaging and System.Xml. Of course, it will be easy only for very simple files.

Comment: Cool thanks, didn't know that. I've been using [ExcelDataReader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) for reading .xlsx. Have a +1

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an Excel file using [OLE DB](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87#OLEDBProviderForMicrosoftJetExcel) provider.

Have a look at this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB).